# How to access the child elements of an element with minidom?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am reading an XML/OWL file (generated from Protege) in Jupyter notebook.

I can read the root element, but for children its showing error/blank.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

DOMTree = parse("pressman.owl")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

if collection.hasAttribute("shelf"):
   print("Root element : %s" % collection.getAttribute("owl:ObjectProperty"))

for objectprop in collection.getElementsByTagName("owl:ObjectProperty"):
    if objectprop.hasAttribute("rdf:about"):
            propertytext = objectprop.getAttribute("rdf:about")
            property = propertytext.split('#',2)
            print ("Property: %s" % property[1])
            type = objectprop.getElementsByTagName('rdf:resource')
            print ("Type: %s" % type)
```

and the `pressman.owl` file (abridged):

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/sraza/ontologies/2021/4/untitled-ontology-6#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/sraza/ontologies/2021/4/untitled-ontology-6"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:PressmanOntology="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#"
     xmlns:UniversityOntology="http://www.semanticweb.org/sraza/ontologies/2021/4/UniversityOntology#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology"/>
    
    <!-- Object Properties -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#hasAdvice"/>

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#hasDefinition">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#SEPressman"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#SEPressman"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#hasDiagram">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#SEPressman"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#SEPressman"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <!-- more entries... -->    
</rdf:RDF>
```

The output fis

```
Property: hasAdvice
Type: []
Property: hasDefinition
Type: []
Property: hasDiagram
Type: []
```

Comment: Don't only include links to external resources , such as shared files on Google Drive. When the link goes away (and it will) then the question becomes useless for any future visitor. I have edited the question to show the code. For reference: That's how your questions on SO are supposed to look like.

Comment: I have aslso removed your sub-question about NLP. That's really a completely different issue, and it was very vague and unfocused. If you have a question about that (ideally it has a bit more meat to it than *"Also I'm trying to do NLP, how can I do that?"*), you're more than welcome to open a new thread that focuses on that topic.

Comment: Don't miss the last-minute edit on my answer, see last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this structure

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#hasDefinition">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#SEPressman"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="urn:absolute:PressmanOntology#SEPressman"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

and you're using

```
type = objectprop.getElementsByTagName('rdf:resource')
```

This cannot work, because `rdf:resource` is not an element, it's an attribute. I assume the one you're interested in belongs to `<rdf:type>`. So we need to go one more level down:

```
rdf_type = objectprop.getElementsByTagName('rdf:type')
```

Now `rdf_type` is a node list - after all the method is called *"get element**s** by tag name"*, and minidom cannot know that there only might be a single `<rdf:type>` in your case. We take the first one, if it exists:

```
rdf_type = rdf_type[0] if len(rdf_type) > 0 else None
```

Now `rdf:resource` is an attribute on that element. Attributes are accessed through `.getAttribute()` in minidom.

In theory, the `rdf:resource` attribute could be is missing in the XML, so let's make sure it exists before using it:

```
if rdf_type is not None and rdf_type.hasAttribute('rdf:resource'):
    rdf_resource = rdf_type.getAttribute('rdf:resource')
else:
    rdf_resource = None

print(rdf_resource)
```

---

All that being said, instead of manually wrestling with RDF files, it might be worthwhile to check out libraries that were written for RDF, such as [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib), or even for OWL specifically, such as [pyLODE](https://github.com/RDFLib/).